# Does a server that serves a form requesting a user's credit card information need to be PCI compliant

Tags: forms, security, credit-card, pci-dss

I'm building a new web application that serves a form requesting the user's card information. Submitting this form will post the form data to a different, fully PCI-DSS compliant application.

Does the application that serves the form to users need to be PCI-DSS compliant also, even if I don't read card information in that application?

As far as my brief googling session has shown, it seems that PCI-DSS compliance is required in any application that "handles" card information. I'm not entirely sure where "handling" that information begins and ends.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PCI/DSS was updated in 2014 (with requirements that became mandatory in Jan 2015) to deal with services mechanisms like that used by stripe in the form of a more stringent self assessment questionnaire ([SAQ A-EP V3](https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/documents/SAQ_A-EP_v3.pdf)) which is described as:

> New SAQ to address requirements applicable to e-commerce merchants
>   with a websites that do not themselves receive cardholder data but
>   which do affect the security of the payment transaction and/or the
>   integrity of the page that accepts the consumer’s cardholder data.
>   Content aligns with PCI DSS v3.0 requirements and testing procedures.

This makes it clear that compliancy is required.

Answer (score 0):

Your use case sounds similar to Stripe's, and they say you'd need to use SSL on your page but otherwise can self-attest to compliance.

https://support.stripe.com/questions/do-i-need-to-be-pci-compliant-what-do-i-have-to-do

You may want to consult an auditor and get a formal opinion from them, though.